# How to deploy java application on different server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish-4, apache-tomee

If i want to deploy one application on different servers like Open Source Glassfish or TomEE. How can I achieve that without having to include different libraries for each application server? As an example if would like to use Jersey as the rest framework and eclipselink as the persistence framework i have to make sure both support these frameworks. But in case of TomEE it's shipped with other implementations like OpenJPA.

Is it possible to ship the dependencies only with the project and not in combination of server libraries + project libraries?
What is a good way to achieve server compatibility?

Any information or link which describes a solution or help me understand why it's done this way would be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a application server classloading issue and usually all application servers have a provision for a configuration file which you can put in your application and instruct the server to load the libraries included in the web application instead of the one present in application server. For e.g., Weblogic has a `weblogic.xml` file which is put in `WEB-INF` of war application and where you can instruct server to prefer the application packaged libraries. For JBoss there is similar configuration file `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`. This way it is easier to have a self contained application which contains all dependencies even if the server has equivalent libraries. Also you can upgrade to higher version of libraries than supported by application server otherwise you have to resort to all sort of hacks.

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution I can think of is using [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) task to create war file for each servers. You can have at most 2-3 servers in reality like tomcat ee, jboss and glasfish. So create 3 ant tasks for each like tomcatWar, jbossWar and glassfishWar and each ant task makes sure required jars are shipped as well in the war. This is more easy and extendable solution, also easy to understand and modify for new requirements.